# Why doesn't await Task.Run() sync back to UI Thread / origin context?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, async-await, task

I thought I understood the **async-wait pattern** and the `Task.Run` operation.
But I am wondering why in the following code example the `await` does not sync back to the UI thread after returning from the finished task.

```cs
public async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); // "Thread: 1"
    double value = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); // Thread: 6

        // Do some CPU expensive stuff
        double x = 42;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
        {
            x += i - Math.PI;
        }
        return x;
    }).ConfigureAwait(true);
    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {value}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"); // Thread: 6  - WHY??
}
```

This code runs within a .NET Framework WPF application on a Windows 10 system with attached Visual Studio 2019 Debugger.
I am calling this code from the constructor of my `App` class.

```cs
public App()
{
    this.InitializeAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);
}
```

Maybe it is not the the best way, but I am not sure if this is the reason for the weird behaviour.

The code starts with the UI thread and should do some Task.
With the `await` operation and `ConfigureAwait(true)` after the Task finishes it should continue on the Main Thread (1). But it does not.

Why?

Comment: @SushantYelpale incorrect

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a tricky thing.

You are calling `await` on UI thread, it's true. But! You are doing it inside `App`'s constructor.

Remember that the implicitly generated startup code looks like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var app = new YourNamespace.App();
    app.InitializeComponent();
    app.Run();
}
```

The event loop, which is used for returning back to the main thread, is started only as a part of `Run` execution. So during the `App` constructor run, there is no event loop. Yet.

As a consequence, the `SynchronizationContext`, which is technically responsible for return of the flow to the main thread after `await`, is `null` at the App's constructor.

(`SynchronizationContext` is captured by `await` *before* waiting, so it doesn't matter that *after* finishing the `Task` there is already a valid `SynchronizationContext`: the captured value is `null`, so `await` continues execution on a thread pool thread.)

So the problem is not that you are running the code in a constructor, the problem is that you are running it in the `App`'s constructor, at which point the application is not yet fully set up for execution. The same code in `MainWindow`'s constructor would behave well.

Let's make some experiment:

```
public App()
{
    Console.WriteLine($"sc = {SynchronizationContext.Current?.ToString() ?? "null"}");
}

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"sc = {SynchronizationContext.Current?.ToString() ?? "null"}");
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

The first output gives

```
sc = null
```

the second

```
sc = System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext
```

So you can see that already in `OnStartup` there is a synchronization context. So if you move `InitializeAsync()` into `OnStartup`, it will behave as you'd expect it.